# Move element from vector A to vector B (not empty) in reverse order

Tags: c++, vector

I need to push all elements from vector `bacward_segment` in reverse order into `forward_segment`.

This is my code:

```
for(int q = backward_segment.size()-1; q >= 0; q--){
                forward_segment.push_back(backward_segment[q]);
        }
```

But I think is not so efficient.. Can you suggest to me a better solution?

Comment: you can use `std::copy_if`, but I doubt it will make it more efficient

Comment: Read about `std::reverse_copy`.

Comment: do you need to move, or to copy them?

Comment: I bet you can achieve your actual goal by skipping the copy/move/whatever and just iterating backwards at point of use (and skipping when duplicates are found).

Answer (score 4):

## If copy is enough

If you're initializing `forward_segment` it's as simple as

```
vector<T> forward_segment(backward_segment.crbegin(), backward_segment.crend());
```

otherwise:

```
forward_segment.resize(backward_segment.size());
copy(backward_segment.crbegin(), backward_segment.crend(), forward_segment.begin());
```

## If you actually need to move elements

Use [`make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator) (note that I'm not using const iterators for this).

Initialization:

```
vector<T> forward_segment(
    make_move_iterator(backward_segment.rbegin()),
    make_move_iterator(backward_segment.rend())
);
```

otherwise:

```
forward_segment.resize(backward_segment.size());
copy(
    make_move_iterator(backward_segment.rbegin()),
    make_move_iterator(backward_segment.rend()),
    forward_segment.begin()
);
```

Comment: There is `if` condition there

Comment: Neither is there a need for one in the question: *I need to push all elements from vector `bacward_segment` in reverse order into `forward_segment`*

Comment: He also says that he need to "move" elements, why you ignored that then?

Answer (score 1):

> But I think is not so efficient..

You should not "think" about that. Use profiler instead. Optimization by guessing almost never works.

> Can you suggest to me a better solution?

You can reserve size of `forward_segment` to `backward_segment`'s size if you expect not too many duplicates would be skipped. Better optimization could be done on algorithm level, for example skipping whole copy at all, but you do not provide enough information for that.

You can use `std::unique_copy`:

```
std::unique_copy( backward_segment.rbegin(), backward_segment.rend(),
                  std::back_inserter( forward_segment ),
                  []( const auto &s1, const auto &s2 ) {
                       return s1.x == s2.x && s1.y == s2.y;
                  } );
```

it would make it more readable (in my opinion), but compexity would be pretty much the same.